# Serviço GET - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, nullpointerexception

Estou atuando na criação de um serviço `Get` no ASP.NET Core, meu projeto contém a seguinte estrutura:

Certidao.Data - Class Library

Dentro dela tem `Dependences`, `Models`: `Sexo.cs` e `DB_SDO_DEVContext.cs`

#### DB_SDO_DEVContext.cs

```
public DB_SDO_DEVContext(DbContextOptions<DB_SDO_DEVContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

#### Sexo.cs

```
public partial class Sexo
{
    public Sexo()
    {
        Pesvtmocrctdatd = new HashSet<Pesvtmocrctdatd>();
    }

    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Abreviacao { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Pesvtmocrctdatd> Pesvtmocrctdatd { get; set; }
}
```

#### Repositories> Interfaces: ISexoRepository.cs

```
{
public interface ISexoRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Sexo> ConsultaSexoIds(List<int> ids);
}
}
```

#### SexoRepository.cs

```
    public class SexoRepository : RepositoryBase<Sexo>, ISexoRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Sexo> ConsultaSexoIds(IEnumerable<int> ids)
        {
            using (var Db = new DB_SDO_DEVContext())
            {
                return (from sexo in Db.Sexo
                        where ids.Contains(sexo.Id)
                        select sexo).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### SexoController.cs

```
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class SexoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DB_SDO_DEVContext contexto;

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Sexo>> GetAll()
    {
        return contexto.Sexo.ToList();
    }

}
}
```

Um erro ocorre quando chega na `SexoController`, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Visual Studio com o erro]

Por que deu este erro na minha implementação? Só estou tentando trazer dados da tabela `Sexo` do SQL Server ao tentar rodar meu método `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obrigado por me ajudar a respeito da instancia de objeto, porém a forma mais simples de se trazer os dados da tabela sexo quando executei o serviço Get na minha SexoController, ficou da seguinte forma:

```
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]

public class SexoController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DB_SDO_DEVContext _contexto = new DB_SDO_DEVContext();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Sexo>> GetAll()
    {
            return _contexto.Sexo.ToList();
    }

}
```

}

Agora sim, usando o programa Postman, foi percorrido o código e o resultado veio abaixo:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "descricao": "Masculino",
    "abreviacao": "M",
    "pesvtmocrctdatd": []
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "descricao": "Feminino",
    "abreviacao": "F",
    "pesvtmocrctdatd": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "descricao": "Indeterminado",
    "abreviacao": "I",
    "pesvtmocrctdatd": []
}
```

]

Answer (score 1):

O erro é auto explicativo, você está tentando acessar um objeto que não foi instanciado, então seu valor é nulo, não tem nada que possa fazer com ele e por isso dá um erro.

A solução para isso é inicializar o objeto, e só você sabe como fazê-lo de acordo com a necessidade de sua aplicação, mas uma forma que evitará este erro, mesmo que cause outro mais pra frente seria:

```
public class SexoController : ControllerBase {
    private readonly DB_SDO_DEVContext contexto;
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Sexo>> GetAll() {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DB_SDO_DEVContext>();
        contexto = new DB_SDO_DEVContext(optionsBuilder.Options)
        return contexto.Sexo.ToList();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/EntityFramework/InitObject.cs).

Mesmo isso só não vai dar problema porque a execução é efêmera, em outras condições deveria liberar o recurso, como fez no repositório (que não sei se deveria ser criado assim).

Desta forma está atribuindo um valor com um objeto desta classe. O `new` cria o objeto.

Claro que se não funcionar como quer precisa aprender todos os detalhes da ferramenta que está usando.

Alias este é um dos piores nomes de classe que eu já vi.